# reading and printing matrix using pointer to pointer method

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks

I wrote a program for reading and printing the matrix without making use of array of pointers. The program is reading and printing matrix correctly, but it crashes after the execution. There are no warnings in the program. Unable to find what is wrong with the program. I am using Codeblock+mingw
Also is this method of using pointer to pointer for two dimensional matrix is OK or any better method?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
   int numCols=2;
   int numRows=2;
   int *cols;
   int rowCount;
   int colCount;
   cols=(int*) malloc(numCols*sizeof(int));
   int **rows;
   rows= (int**) malloc(numRows*sizeof(cols));

   printf("Filling the rows and Columns\n");

   for(rowCount=0;rowCount<numRows;rowCount++)
   {
       printf("Fill Row Number %d\n",rowCount);
       for(colCount=0;colCount<numCols;colCount++)
       {
           printf("Enter the value to be read\n");
           scanf("%d",(*(rows+rowCount)+colCount));
       }
   }

   // Printing the values
     for(rowCount=0;rowCount<numRows;rowCount++)
   {
       printf("Print Row Number %d\n",rowCount);
       for(colCount=0;colCount<numCols;colCount++)
       {
           printf("%d\t",*(*(rows+rowCount)+colCount));
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   free(rows);
   free(cols);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no matrix (aka 2D array!

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: Wht does the debugger say? Provide a [mcve]. Your code seems very broken. May I suggest you search for a tutorial about pointer and arrays? This is no offence, but you really seem to be lacking some basic concepts and SO is not the place to teach.

Comment: Is he not allocating more memory(24Bytes) than what is required(16Bytes) ?

Comment: `cols=(int*) malloc(numCols*sizeof(int));` need each rows.

Comment: Hmm, yeah but the column pointers are not pointing to the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allocating memory in the right manner. Your program crashes because of illegal memory access it makes.

What's Cols array for; as you're never storing any integer in it and its extra. Second rows is a an array int* not int. One of the ways to allocate a 2D array will be

```
int** matrix;
matrix = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *));
matrix[0] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * c * r);

//To access elements
for(rowCount=0;rowCount<numRows;rowCount++)
{
   printf("Fill Row Number %d\n",rowCount);
   for(colCount=0;colCount<numCols;colCount++)
   {
       printf("Enter the value to be read %d %d \n", rowCount, colCount);
       scanf("%d",(*matrix+rowCount*numCols)+colCount);
   }
}
//free it as
free(matrix);
```

Its always a good practice to allocate and access row-wise in C to so that memory fetches are not bottle-neck.

## Update

Yes you can allocate memory like this. 
`rows= (int**) malloc(numRows * numCols * sizeof(int)); //Yes sizeof(int)`.

Its perfectly legal statement in C. It will allocate `numRows * numCols` sized array of integer pointers with each element of size equal to `sizeof(int)`.

It may cause trouble on 64bit platform where pointers are 8 byte long.

Even assuming it to be 32bit platform there is another problem. How will you dereference `rows` for your intended purpose? rows[i] will be a pointer to integer i.e. int* type; but doing scanf on that will give you a segmentation fault as row[i] will contain some garbage value and might lead you to some unwanted area in memory.

Comment: Yes, I agree that cols array not needed. I will change the implementation as you suggested. But can't we allocate memory something like this?  rows= (int**) malloc(numRows * numCols * sizeof(int));. mallock ultimately allocates so many bytes correct?

Comment: In your last comment, Why ** comes for scanf also? For address one * shall be reduced I thought. Now How to printf the value now using same concept? *(**rows+rowCount)+colCount) did not work